# Is it possible to automatically force SQLCMD mode in script?

Tags: sql, sqlcmd, ssms

We're using Visual Studio Database Professional and it makes heavy use of SQLCMD variables to differentiate between environments while deploying.

I know there's several directives available for setting context (like :connect for server name). Is there a way within the script itself to force SQLCMD mode for execution? Part of our deployment process is to have DBA's examine and execute the scripts and it would be a nice safety net (so I don't have to remind them to set their execution mode to SQLCMD).

Comment: +1 Looking for a similar solution. Ever find out how to do it?

Comment: No, still waiting. I'm hesitant to start a bounty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a solution, but as a work-around, you could embed your script in some warning.  [This post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5468/can-i-enable-sqlcmd-mode-from-inside-a-script) inspired me to this code:

```
SET NOEXEC OFF; -- previous execution may have toggled it
:setvar IsSqlCmdEnabled "True"
GO
IF ('$(IsSqlCmdEnabled)' = '$' + '(IsSqlCmdEnabled)')
BEGIN
  PRINT('Use SqlCmd-mode!!');
  SET NOEXEC ON;
  -- RAISERROR ('This script must be run in SQLCMD mode.', 20, 1) WITH LOG
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  PRINT('Using SqlCmd-mode')
  -- insert the code you really want to execute:
  -- ...
END
SET NOEXEC OFF; -- do not disable next execution in this session
```

Comment: I know this is late but for anyone else who finds this in the future: the VS2010 publish scripts do basically this (they set a special `__IsSqlCmdEnabled` var then immediately check it's value) but they also `SET NOEXEC ON` as an added safety measure to prevent anything else in the script from running.

Comment: @Micheal, thanks for the tip, I added the `NOEXEC`. (Untested, no SqlServer around at this moment, but it looks simple enough.)

Comment: @Paul: that's because `NOEXEC` is still on for this session, and commands (inc. printing) will not be executed.  If you end (and/or start) the command sequence with `SET NOEXEC OFF` it will repeat.  To save people the trouble of having to type that (and think of that), I will also add that to the example.

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem to be possible.  I even checked the SSMS project mode.

However, if you create a database project in BIDS, the pre-deploy & post-deploy scripts run in SQLCMD mode by default.

I know that is not the answer you want, but it is the best I can give you w/o resorting creating a custom SSMS plugin that would do it for you based on some text in the script file.